# custom binding is not firing update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, custom-binding

I am working with system that is using Knockout.js and Jquery Mobile UI combination. One of the issues I ran into was getting Jquery Mobile being applied on elements that have `knockout :if` bindings. Initial solution we were using was in page cycle fire events when `ko.applyBindings` and `ko.valueHasMutated` are being called and then in event handlers calling the following

```
$(element).find('div[data-onthemovecollapsible="true"]:not(div[data-role="collapsible"])').attr("data-role", "collapsible");
$(element).collapsibleset().collapsibleset("refresh");
```

Problem was this sometimes would get called to many times or sometimes someone would forget to trigger required events and would produce same bugs over and over again so business has decided move this mechanism to custom binding with following logic: If element is bound (becomes visible or some other way ends up on a page) then apply JQuery mobile UI. `init` of custom binding would be equivalent of `ko.applyBindings` and `update` equivalent of `ko.valueHasMutated`. 
It worked fine for when list 'appears' on the page however when pagination or filtering is being used model is not being 're-bound' only viewModel array is being changed and `ko.valueHasMutated` is being called. I have just found out that `update` is not getting called when value has mutated is being fired. I have done some reading around and this seems to be a known issue however none of the solutions seem to work in my case

```
ko.bindingHandlers.expandableListJQM = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).find('div[data-onthemovecollapsible="true"]:not(div[data-role="collapsible"])').attr("data-role", "collapsible");
        $(element).collapsibleset().collapsibleset("refresh");
        var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (val!= undefined) {
             valueAccessor().subscribe(function (element, valueAccessor) {
                $(element).find('div[data-onthemovecollapsible="true"]:not(div[data-role="collapsible"])').attr("data-role", "collapsible");
                $(element).collapsibleset().collapsibleset("refresh");
            });
        }
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).find('div[data-onthemovecollapsible="true"]:not(div[data-role="collapsible"])').attr("data-role", "collapsible");
        $(element).collapsibleset().collapsibleset("refresh");
    }
};
```

even if I am subscribing to `valueAccessor()` like in example  `function (element, valueAccessor) {...` it's not of much use to me as variable that is being passed as `element` is empty array and not something usefull.
I could start applying   `.collapsibleset().collapsibleset` by using JQuery selector as I know what ID list has, but it does not feel like a proper solution, we might as well leave that hack we had previously.

**How can I on `ko.valueHasMutated` make knockout.js custom binding `update` fire with proper arguments being passed?**

Comment: I can't quite follow what you are doing nor what the issue is.  Could you reproduce this problem in a fiddle and we could probably help you pinpoint the issue or a way to make it work properly?

Comment: @PWKad It's not a bug request, code in UPDATE works ok, but the way it's done is wrong. There's is a reason that custom binding has `init` and `update`, first is used for initial binding the other one is for subsequent value changes (or at least that's the way I understand it). Code in UPDATE is workaround - what I am looking is for proper solution (that would on `valueHasMutated` e.g model update would invoke custom binding `update`). You seem to be an expert in knockout let me know if I am missing something here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being I am using this solution as I know someone is going to propose it. But this is only a hack and I would prefer a 'proper' solution from someone.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.expandableListJQM = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).find('div[data-onthemovecollapsible="true"]:not(div[data-role="collapsible"])').attr("data-role", "collapsible");
        $(element).collapsibleset().collapsibleset("refresh");
        var element =  $(element);
        var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (val!= undefined) {
             valueAccessor().subscribe(function() {
                $(element).find('div[data-onthemovecollapsible="true"]:not(div[data-role="collapsible"])').attr("data-role", "collapsible");
                $(element).collapsibleset().collapsibleset("refresh");
            });
        }
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).find('div[data-onthemovecollapsible="true"]:not(div[data-role="collapsible"])').attr("data-role", "collapsible");
        $(element).collapsibleset().collapsibleset("refresh");
    }
};
```